# Measure Function

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(\Omega , U, \mu)$ be a measure space and $(\Omega' , U')$ be a measurable space. 
$f: \Omega \to \Omega'$ is a measurable function, $g: \Omega' \to \mathbb R$ is a measurable function and $ g\circ  f: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ is a measurable function.
$$ \mu_f :U' \to \mathbb R$$
$$A' \to \mu_f(A')=\mu(f^{-1}(A'))$$
$\mu_f$ is a measure.

I have no idea what $\mu_f$ is. How can I show $\mu_f$ is a measure? It is lebesgue-stieltjes measure? If it is not, what is it? I am new in measure theory. I am stuck in this topic.

Comment: Is it $(\Omega, U)$ or $(\Omega', U')$?

Comment: @Atbey It is $(\Omega' , U')$. I missed it

Comment: What does $g$ has to do with $\mu_f$? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu_f$ is **defined** as $\mu_f(A') = \mu(f^{-1}(A'))$. It's not the Lebesgue-Stieljes measure. You need to show that $\mu_f(A') \geq 0$, that $\mu_f(\varnothing) = 0$, and that $\mu_f(\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty A_n') = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \mu_f(A_n')$ for all countable disjoint collections of sets in $U'$. That is, you need to show it satisfies the measure axioms.

This is called the "measure induced by $f$", or the "measure pullback of $f$".

Comment: Also, $g$ is a red herring, and has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: thanks @Duncan. I was really confused. I have never seen these topics. I hope I understand these topics as soon as possible.

Comment: @statistic Good luck in your studies!